# kohana parse $_POST data

Tags: php, forms, post, kohana

i have a kohana application, and i have a form with several checkboxes, and the user is supposed to check his preferences there in the form. so i have a relation 1:n between the user table and the preferences table. my problem is that i want to save those preferences, selected in the form, and i don;t know how.

i have the form:

```
   <form id="address" method="POST" action="<?= Route::url('Save user preferences' , array('user_id' => $user));?>">
   <? foreach ($prefered_products as $pp): ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="user_preferences_preference[]" value="<?= $pp ?>" /><?= $pp->product; ?><br />

   <? endforeach; ?>
            <button type="submit">Salveaza preferintele tale</button>
   </form>
```

and i save the data:

```
  foreach ($_POST['user_preferences_preference'] as $up)  {
     $user_preferences->prefered = $up;
     $user_preferences->user = $this->user;
     $user_preferences->save();

    }
$this->view->message = __('Thank you for your feedback!');
```

but seems like the way i parse the preferences is not correct, i am getting: ErrorException [ Warning ]: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

any idea about how am i supposed to get the multiple $_post preferences?
thank you!

Comment: It means that `$_POST['user_preferences_preference']` is not an array (or a Traversable). Have you tried `var_dump`ing it?

Comment: Is the warning occurring only when you check no checkboxes?

Comment: Use `$data = Arr::get($_POST, 'user_preferences_preference', array())` or `$data = (array)$_POST['user_preferences_preference']`.

Comment: I suggest you do not use the old syntax of PHP `<?= $ Var;?>` Instead use `<?php echo $ var;?>` And instead of `<? foreach ($ prefered_products as $ pp):?>`
uses `<?php foreach ($ prefered_products as $ pp):?>` because kohana is thought to php 5 and these are conventions that were deprecated.

Comment: Please use $this->request->post() instead of $_POST, it is HMVC safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a checkbox will only post data when set. You should reverse check the values. Ie;

- Fetch all preference (id's) from the database
- Check if a value is found in the $_POST var
- If not, update to false (or 0 or whatever) in db, if set, read out the value.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different way of doing this.

When I create a checkbox I also create an identical hidden field set to zero

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_check" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check" value="$value" />
```

The checkbox, if ticked, will override the hidden value.  This way when you send the form you end up with $_POST['checkbox]=1 or 0, but it always exists in the $_POST.

The nice thing about this method is you can extend the Form::checkbox helper so that it's always present and you don't have to worry about it for every form / controller.

p.s. in you above example you would probably want to do it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_preferences_preference[$pp->id]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="user_preferences_preference[$pp->id]" value="<?= $pp ?>" />
<?= $pp->product; ?><br />
```

Or use a $key value instead of $pp->id.